# "equalable", "equalizable", or none of them?

Tags: adjectives, deverbal-adjectives

What is (or which are) the proper adjective to denote "two things that can be made equal (in a mathematical sense)".

Both the words "equalable" and "equalizable" have been used, but it is unclear to me whether they are correct (or at least admissible).

Which one is more advisable? Is there a better alternative to them?

**Edit**
The context is quite technical, but a reasonable approximation would be that of two formal expressions having a common variable, say x. Then, the two expressions are ''equalable'' if they are equal for at least one value of x. For example:

The expressions "x*x" and "2*x" are equalable (taking x=2).

The expressions "x*0" and "x/x" are not equalable.

Comment: What sort of things? Can you give us an example sentence? 'Equivalent' might work, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @marcellothearcane See the edit to the question. "Equivalent" will not work because of course there are values of x for which the expressions are not equal. They are equal just for some values of x.

Comment: I have not heard *equalable* used for mathematics. Instead, I have heard "What are the roots of x^2=2x?" or "how many solutions are there for x/x?" or "What is y such that y=x*0?" The answers would be "2", "infinite," or the "the set of all reals," respectively.

Comment: The term 'equilibratable' is found – rarely, but in pretty prestigious articles. It is probably in OED. In maths jargon, you'd expect [∃x ∈ R]: x*x = 2*x

Comment: So x*x and 2x ***intersect***. And 0*x and x/x never intersect.

Comment: *Equatable* as suggested in @Edwin's answer seems to carry the desired meaning. *Equalizable* means able of being equalized; this is actually a useful word in communication engineering with a meaning quite different from what is requested. I could not find it in any dictionary, but a web search shows many instances.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those words you imagine might exist but probably doesn't – and if it does, it will be too obscure to use or have a default meaning other than the one you want. However, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equatable)

> **equatable** adjective: capable of being equated
>
> *different but equatable terminologies* — Ethel Albert

and we surely need the appropriate sense of *equate*:

> **equate** ... transitive verb
>
> 1a: to make equal : EQUALIZE

[[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equate)]

The fact that this is listed first by M-W is encouraging, but that could be because it is the most transparent sense rather than the most common. And even if the 'make equal' sense *is* the most common, this does not mean that 'equatable' might not have the default meaning 'that can be regarded/shown/treated as equivalent'.

'Equalisable', and as mentioned in a comment 'equilibratable', are sometimes found, but it seems more usual to find workarounds.